# Get Object ID of UI element from code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying link 40 buttons to one event handler method and then do the 
processing work from one method instead of 40. I know how to link it 
but once I get there I don't know how to distinguish what button was 
pressed. Does anyone know how to reference the button object sender id 
or is there another way to solve this problem? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understand witch button was pressed you need first to create an IBoutlet into you code for each button and then compare it with `sender` just using the `==` operator.

Example:

```
//test.h
@interface Test : UIViewController {
    UIButton *button1,button2;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender;
```

Compare:

```
//test.m
-(void)click:(id)sender
{
    if (button1 == sender)
    { NSLog(@"Button 1"); }
    else if (button2 == sender)
    { NSLog(@"Button 2"); }
}
```

Comment: @andoriyu.mp: You can use other trivial ways, like the text of the button, but... it's trivial :)